# Is not it possible to use more than 3 output pins in ESP8266 at the same time?

Tags: esp8266, l298n

I'm trying to make a WiFi controlled Car from my old toy car which will be running on ESP8266. I'm using the L298N motor driver and have *one motor for left-right control* & *other for forward-backward direction control*.

Now the problem is I'm unable to use more than 3 pins at once. If I even try, likely my code **stops** working.

Below is my code :

```
static const uint8_t enFront   = D0;
static const uint8_t front_in1 = D1;
static const uint8_t front_in2 = D2;
static const uint8_t enBack    = D5;
static const uint8_t back_in1  = D3;
static const uint8_t back_in2  = D4;

#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "espCar <^_^>";
const char* password = "hacksAllowed";

  ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  pinMode(enFront,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(front_in1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(front_in2,OUTPUT);
 /* pinMode(enBack,OUTPUT);   <--Problem here
  pinMode(back_in1,OUTPUT);   <--Problem here
  pinMode(back_in2,OUTPUT);*/ <--Problem here

   Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  delay(500);  
  server.on("/REQ",processRequest);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server is UP!");  
}

void loop() {
 // server.handleClient(); 
  analogWrite(enFront,1023);
  digitalWrite(front_in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(front_in2,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(front_in2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(front_in1,LOW);
  delay(2000);
}

void processRequest() { 
 /* if (server.arg("move")!=""){
    if (server.arg("right")!=""){
      analogWrite(enFront,server.arg("right").toInt());
      digitalWrite(front_in1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(front_in2,LOW);
      /*Debug*/
    /*  server.send(200, "200", server.arg("right"));
    }else if(server.arg("left")!=""){
      analogWrite(enFront,server.arg("left").toInt());
      digitalWrite(front_in1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(front_in2,HIGH);
      /*Debug*/
     /* server.send(200, "200", server.arg("left"));
    } 
  }*/
}
```

---

***All code working fine until I declare `pinMode(pin,OUTPUT)` for any 4th pin.*** (Everything is ok for every pin till 3rd one is declared)

I'm not so old with ESP or Arduino. So, please help by giving some clarification on this.

---

**Schematic**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBsybo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Sorry for the mistake of making both motors tagged 2, → one is M1 & other is M2**

Comment: scheme? (why did you add tags for other boards? I removed them)

Comment: ok. on the scheme you have a NodeMcu with Dx labels, in the code you use io pin numbers. you can use Dx constants in code.

Comment: pins io 0 and io 2 must be HIGH at boot. it is possible that wiring them to the driver board pulls them down.

Comment: Ok. Actually I used System.println to print out D1 to D5 then used them

Comment: Ok. Then I will test by keeping them HIGH at BOOT... I think that's happening here. Because adding those last 3 pinMode lines blocking me up.

Comment: on the scheme you have D2 (4), D3 (io 0), D4 (io 2) wired

Comment: I'm using other pins. It looks nearly to the sceme but not exact. To simplify wiring and push up everything in a small place I did that. :-(

Comment: Why can't you draw a schematic that is what you actually have?  You might as well show nothing as to show something that isn't true.

Comment: @Delta_G I didn't know about the scematic maker here. **I assume that you've already seen that the site has told me as new contributor*

Comment: @jsotola I didn't know about the scematic maker here. *I assume that you've already seen that the site has told me as new contributor* . I knew the code would be enough to diagnose the problem. Next time I ask a question here I'll keep that in mind and I just updated a exact schema

Comment: In my project I have 4 relays, PWM output, tone() output, 2 output pins for LED bar, I2C ADC, temperature sensor on A0 and a button. that all on Wemos D1 R2 which has the same io to Dx mapping as NodeMcu

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for the support! I've found out what my mistake was

Comment: I almost asked if you did connect the groud, because you don't have it in the schema. I magnified the photo from first version of your question and there were black wires so I thought that was the ground connection. Or are those only shadows?

Comment: It was my first time on this site. So, there was mistake asking the question, I agree. I even didn't know about the schematic maker here. So, took one nearly same and placed it on the question.

If I've placed the question correctly it won't take much time to get answered. I'll remember these the next time I ask here. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem & it has nothing to deal with ESP8266. It was something like voltage conflict (I don't know the deeper science, I agree).

*Actually, I was testing by plugging in the USB to ESP & at the same time I had a 11V lipo connected to L298N.*

I tested by using one single voltage source & everything worked fine.

It looked something like this (It → the wrong one here):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNWxoA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It is acceptable to connect two DC voltage sources like this, except that you should connect the `GND` connections together.

Comment: I did the same but didn't make the `GND` together & likely that was the problem